# How to export an Excel document through a server?

Tags: c#, closedxml

I made a simple web page with some data that can be manipulated and i used ClosedXML to convert that list to an exel document. The data manipulation works fine. The problem is with the Excel conversion.

How am i supposed to program the web page to save the document on the client side? The code bellow works locally, when i test it on my PC, but trying to do that remotly on the server prompts an error.

> Runtime Error
> Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

> Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

I'm not familiar how to make a custom error, yet, but i do get the fact that the problem must be the way i try to save the file. The app tries to save the document on the server's C disk. While i need it to save the file on the client's PC.

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Export", "Home"))
{
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn" type="submit" name="dummy" value="">Export Excel</button>
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Export() //Export Excel
{
    if (staticList.Count > 0)
    {
        // here be the convertion of the data to Excel using ClosedXML
        wb.SaveAs("C:\\BT.xlsx");
        ViewData["sentence"] = "Export made";
    }
    return View("Index", staticList);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Inserting Tables](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Inserting-Tables) doc page shows how you can load a List directly into a spreadsheet using `InsertTable`, using the property names as columns. The method returns a table object that can be used to apply styles, sorting etc :

```
  var list = new List<Person>();
  ...
  var peopleTable= ws.Cell(7, 6).InsertTable(list);
  ...
  peopleTable.Theme = XLTableTheme.TableStyleLight10;

  wb.SaveAs("InsertingData.xlsx");
```

To return the data to the caller, save the workbook to a MemoryStream and return it using `File` method instead of `View`:

```
public ActionResult Export() 
{

...
    using var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    wb.SaveAs(stream);
    var content = stream.ToArray();

    return File(content, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "People.xlsx");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Exporting a file to a client's computer from a web application involves sending the file as a response with the appropriate headers. In your current code, you are saving the file on the `server's C drive`, but you should send it as a `response` to the client's browser so that it can be downloaded to the client's machine. To achieve this, you can modify your code as follows:

```
public ActionResult Export()
{
    if (staticList.Count > 0)
    {
        using (var wb = new XLWorkbook())
        {
            // Add data to the Excel workbook using ClosedXML
            var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");

            // Populate the worksheet with data from your staticList
            // For example:
            for (int i = 0; i < staticList.Count; i++)
            {
                ws.Cell(i + 1, 1).Value = staticList[i].Property1;
                ws.Cell(i + 1, 2).Value = staticList[i].Property2;
                // Add more properties as needed
            }

            // Prepare the file content
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            wb.SaveAs(stream);

            // Set the response headers to prompt the user to download the file
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=BT.xlsx");
            Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ToArray());
            Response.End();
        }
    }

    return View("Index", staticList);
}
```